# Why are transmission lines typically 115, 230, or 500 kV?

Tags: high-voltage, power-engineering, distribution-network

Is there a historical or technical reason why US high-voltage transmission lines are typically 115, 230, or 500 kV? ([ref](https://www.tanc.us/understanding-transmission/transmission-line-design/)). These seem like semi-random numbers. I found that 115 kV goes back to 1917 at least ([source](https://waterandpower.org/museum/Early_Power_Transmission.html)), so maybe an arbitrary choice in 1917 has persisted? And is there any technical reason that doubling the voltage to 230 kV would be better than, say, 250 kV?

(To be specific, I'm not asking why transmission lines use high voltage; I'm asking why these particular voltages are used.)

Comment: *so maybe an arbitrary choice in 1917 has persisted?* as anywhere in large-scale many-stakeholder infrastructure, yes. Train track widths (industrial revolution train networks), paper sizes (zhe Germans being smart and standardizing that, the Americans doing something of their own instead), pipe diameters (large town constructions, zhe Germans standardizing their industrial production [recognize a pattern?]), distribution wire cross-sections, typical design loads for street bridges (… yes. Tanks, pretty certainly.),…

Comment: The interesting question, I 100% agree, is why exactly these numbers emerged (and 110 kV, 220 kV, 380 kV in central Europe; where the medium voltages are AFAICT 10 kV, 20 kV, 30 kV, and a few oddbally 36 kV and 40.5 kV subgrids, next to the railway grids, which run at freaky things like 15 kV at 16.66667 Hz as well as 25 kV at the less batexcrement 50 Hz.)

Comment: An interesting addendum might be, what are the tolerances? The motivation might simply be a total turns ratio of 1000, 2000, etc. between them and residential circuits; factored appropriately for similar magic numbers on the distribution lines inbetween (i.e. 4.8kV, 14.4kV, whatever need to be reachable with reasonably small rational numbers). In that case, if the tolerances are same as residential circuits, a simple turns ratio would suffice. This does seem doubtful, as tap changers have been around a long time.

Comment: I have often been intrigued that in the UK distribution voltages have been 110 percent of some round number: 11, 33, 66, and 132 kV - no 22 kV and the next voltages, at grid level, are 275 and 400 kV.

Answer (score 2):

I did some research and the transmission line voltages are a combination of technical and historical factors. In the early 1900s, limits in insulators and switches made it hard to go above 60 kV. However, an attempt to corner the copper market made prices surge, forcing higher voltages: a 1911 [General Electric Review](https://books.google.com/books?id=2HwhAQAAMAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&pg=PA89#v=onepage&q&f=false) says, "The result was that electrical engineering advanced very much faster than it would have done had copper been less expensive. We were forced to go to voltages very much higher than we would have otherwise dared to use; so 60,000 volts was brought up to 80,000 or 100,000 volts."

Some other historical references that I found.
A [1906 publication](https://books.google.com/books?id=c5AxAQAAMAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&pg=PA615#v=onepage&q&f=false) shows a large variety of voltages up to 60 kV. A [1907 Westinghouse ad](https://books.google.com/books?id=YSZHAQAAMAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&pg=PT18#v=onepage&q&f=false) describes transmission lines "up to and above 115,000 volts". The 1907 book [Long-Distance Electric Power Transmission](https://books.google.com/books?id=UU88AQAAMAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&pg=PA108#v=onepage&q&f=falsehttps://books.google.com/books?id=hz1EAQAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) describes various 60 kV lines and says that oil-break switches work up to 60,000 volts.
A [1908 article](https://books.google.com/books?id=UU88AQAAMAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&pg=PA108#v=onepage&q&f=false) says that 60 kV lines are in use but there is great difficulty in finding an insulator for 75 kV. General Electric was [advertising](https://books.google.com/books?id=WzNDAQAAMAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&pg=PA1053-IA2#v=onepage&q&f=false) components for 115 kV lines in 1909. A [1911 report on high tension cables](https://books.google.com/books?id=YSZHAQAAMAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&pg=PT18#v=onepage&q&f=false) describes how paper insulation could go up to 25 kV and work was progressing on rubber insulation that could handle 50 or 60 kV.  A 1913 [article](https://books.google.com/books?id=pIVAAQAAMAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&pg=PT252#v=onepage&q&f=false) mentions that generating 115 kV ensure delivery of 100 kV after transmission losses. A 220 kV line was proposed in [1921](https://books.google.com/books?id=nsiuX0Q1NpcC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&pg=PA204#v=onepage&q&f=false), generating 230 kV for delivery of 220 kV.

The book [Principles of Electric Power Transmission and Distribution](https://books.google.com/books?id=vYxRAAAAMAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q&f=false) (1925) has a nice table showing the (approximately linear) growth in voltage:

[image: Table showing highest voltage by year, from 4 kilovolts in 1889 to 220 kilovolts in 1923)]

My conclusion is that there are technical reasons to use 60 kV but higher voltages are essentially arbitrary numbers driven by economic factors.